# Find and save loop (MongoDB Node Express)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have this controller which fetch data from instagram api.

```
controller.prototype.getData = function getData(url, tag, callback) {
        var clientId = '81e3d3f35c8a4438964001decaa5a31f'
        var catchAll = [];
        var config = {
            'params': {
                'client_id': clientId,
                'callback': 'JSON_CALLBACK'
            }
        }
        vm.url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + tag + '/media/recent/';

        http.jsonp(url, config)
            .then(function(response) {
                vm.imageData = vm.imageData.concat(response.data.data);
                vm.instagram.storeData(vm.imageData).then(function(response) {

                })
                var paging = response.data.pagination;
                if (paging.hasOwnProperty('next_url')) {
                    getData(paging.next_url)
                } else {
                    callback.call();
                }
            })



    }
```

then on node mongodb controller i have this

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
var dataObj = req.body;
dataObj.forEach(function(item) {

    Data.find({
        'id': item.id
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return handleError(res, err);
        }

        if (data.length == 0) {
            Data.create(item, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    return handleError(res, err);
                }
            });
        }

    });

});
```

};

The logic here is that if user is not existing in the collection i will save it. my question is why is it that it takes too long to response if  have lets say 300 instagram object ? is there a ways how to do this in optimal performance?

Comment: You're apparently not responding anything unless there is an error.

Comment: even so it should be faster saving just 400 keys

Comment: Exactly, but as you're not responding anything and that `nodejs` is expecting you to send a response that you never send, then you're probably waiting for something that will never happen, yet the 400 keys will be updated really fast.